# Excessive Logs from MDS in Console

Tags: spotlight, console, mds

On my Mac, In the Console, there is an excessive amount of logging from the 'mds' process.

mds is the service that runs Spotlight.  It is also integral to Time Machine, apparently.

Small sample (In the last 8 minutes, over 240,000 messages have been logged):

```
Date & Time Category    Process Message
2021-05-13 14:31:00.089632 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.089757 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.090442 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.090862 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.091281 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.091833 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.092386 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.093219 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.093765 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.094511 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.095089 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.095727 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.096749 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.097218 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.097585 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.097944 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.098345 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.098795 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.099081 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.099400 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.099740 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.100123 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.100474 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.100847 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.101130 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.101387 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.101629 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.102011 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.102361 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.102844 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.103164 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.103754 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.104052 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.138314 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.139141 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
2021-05-13 14:31:00.139709 -0400    default mds Reading localized string from /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations
```

You can see from the timestamps that these are occurring frequently (every 0.001 or so).

Note: I enabled Private Data in the Console using the instructions here: https://superuser.com/a/1532052/1247878 .

This issue this is causing me (other than being unsightly) is that a diagnostic tool for my VPN wants to collect Console logs over the past day, and the report file it's generating grows to double-digit GB sizes, making it nearly impossible to submit to the network team for troubleshooting.

Is there any way to reduce mds' logging level?  I could turn off the indexing, but then that would affect Time Machine.

Mac Specs:

```
  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro14,3
  Processor Name:   Quad-Core Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.9 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 8 MB
  Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled
  Memory:   16 GB
```

Comment: Is MDS going nuts (using lots of RAM or CPU)? see http://www.rawinfopages.com/mac/content/mdworker-and-mds-osx-problems-solved-speed-your-mac for how to fix that..

Comment: Not too crazy.  But I do know how to stop MDS (or at least, pause it for a while).  As a stop gap, I ran without Spotlight and Time Machine for a day, and cleared all logs so I could get a cleaner diagnostic report.  The logging is still unsightly though.